# Post-Redirect-Get issue in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to use Post-Redirect-Get to show data, which I entered in "Information" page on "Index" page. I have the following methods, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even redirect me on submit. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Information()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Get info
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Submit(Models.Information FirstName,
                               Models.Information LastName,
                               Models.Information DateOfBirth,
                               Models.Information HourOfBirth,
                               Models.Information NumberOfKids,
                               Models.Information Emso,
                               Models.Information Email,
                               Models.Information PlaceOfBirth)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Models.Information info = new Models.Information();

            info.FirstName = FirstName.ToString();
            info.LastName = LastName.ToString();
            info.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfBirth);
            info.HourOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(HourOfBirth);
            info.NumberOfKids = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfKids);
            info.Emso = Emso.ToString();
            info.Email = Email.ToString();
            info.PlaceOfBirth = PlaceOfBirth.ToString();

            TempData["info"] = info;

            return RedirectToAction("Summary");
        }

        return View();
    }

    //Show info
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(Models.Information info)
    {
        info.FirstName = ViewData["FirstName"].ToString();
        info.LastName = ViewData["LastName"].ToString();
        info.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewData["DateOfBirth"]);
        info.HourOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(ViewData["HourOfBirth"]);
        info.NumberOfKids = Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["NumberOfKids"]);
        info.Emso = ViewData["Emso"].ToString();
        info.Email = ViewData["Email"].ToString();
        info.PlaceOfBirth = ViewData["PlaceOfBirth"].ToString();

        return View();
    }
}
```

I try to show data on Index page like this:

```
 First name: <input type='text' runat="server" value="@ViewData["FirstName"]" /><br />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks sort of confusing to me and I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  But first, let's use an example on what I *think* you are trying to accomplish.

1. User enters information on the information action/view
2. (POST)This is POSTed to a controller/action which then verifies the model and puts in into the ViewData (REDIRECT TO STEP 3)
3. (GET)You want to redisplay this data on a summary page.

Under those assumptions, lets clean up your code a bit, leverage the use of the ViewData and TempData objects and see if we can make this work.

**Information Action**

```
public ActionResult Information()
    {
        //In a strongly typed view, typically you would send an empty model
        //so the model binder/Html.Input helpers have something to bind to
        return View(new Models.Information());
    }
```

**Information POST to handle incoming data**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Information(Models.Information info)
{
    //Yup - you can use the same action name as the GET action above
    //You can name this anything you want, but I typically keep the same names so 
    //I know where the data came from

    //I think your assignments are backwards.  info came into the controller action
    //You want to save this as ViewData.  Also, let's do that in one line of code
    //And since we are redirecting, lets use the TempData dictionary

    //Notice the method type decorator above [HttpPost].  This is the P in PRG (Post)

if(modelState.IsValid()){
    TempData["info"] = info;

    //Notice the name of the ActionMethod below.  The is the R in PRG (Redirect)
    return RedirectToAction("Summary");
}

//There were errors, lets send back to the Information view
return View(info);
```

}

**Summary Action**

```
public ActionResult Summary()
    {
        //We were redirected here, and this is a GET method.  This is the G in PRG
        //(GET)

        //lets go ahead and set the TempData stuff to a model, it just looks nicer on
        //the view
        var model = TempData["info"];
        return View(model);
    }
```

As for the views, here is a snippet of what each might look olike

**Information View**

```
@model Models.Information

@{using(Html.BeginForm()){
   @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.FirstName)<br/>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Firstname)

   //Repeat for each property

   <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
}}
```

**Summary View**

```
@model Models.Information

   @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.FirstName)<br/>
   @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Firstname)

   //Repeat for each property
```

Comment: Very well explained. Works like a charm. Thank you so much!